# Запись строки в текстовый файт c#

Tags: c#

Читаю текст из файла, нужно его обработать вставить в другой файл.File.WriteAllText() не подходит так как он чистит файл перед записью. Использовал два способа они закомментированы и не один из них не работает. В чем может быть проблема?

```
    public static void EditorText(string a)
    {

        string newText = Regex.Replace(a, "[\"-.?!)(,:]", "");
        newText = string.Join(" ", newText.Split(' ').Distinct());

        //var test = File.AppendText(@"C:путь");
        //test.WriteLine(newText);

        // StreamWriter test2 = new StreamWriter(@"C:путь");
        // test2.WriteLine(newText);
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:путь", Encoding.Default);
        var test = sr.ReadToEnd();
        EditorText(test);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: File.AppendAllText

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.appendtext?view=netframework-4.7.2

```
using (var test = File.AppendText(@"C:путь"))
{
    test.WriteLine(newText);
}
```

Comment: Благодарю. Буду внимательнее читать документацию.